# OS X .dmg signature lost after download

Tags: macos, download, digital-signature, osx-gatekeeper

I'm signing a `.dmg` containing a `.app` with a valid Developer ID profile. Everything is signed, frameworks included. When I run `codesign -dvvv`, the right certificate appears and `satisfies its Designated Requirement`. The application runs fine.

However, when I upload and download the `.dmg`, the signature "disappears". When I run `codesign -dvvv`, it says `code object is not signed at all`. And GateKeeper naturally refuses to run the application.

Note: it sounds a lot like [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11675066/download-breaks-osx-signature) but I'm definitely signing with the right Developer ID certificate, and the `.dmg` does not appear "damaged".

Comment: Do you need to sign the disk image? I would have thought that just signing the contents of the image would be suitable enough.

Comment: Some browsers don't like unsigned `.dmg`. I will retry without signing the image.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Note: the situation changed significantly in OS X v10.11.5 and v10.12; this answer has been updated to reflect that.]

In general, the thing you really need to sign is the files (mainly the app) inside the disk image, not the image itself. After the image is downloaded, the signature on the individual items will be checked as they are used. Starting in OS X 10.11.5, signing disk images is properly supported and sometimes required, but that's in addition to signing the relevant items inside it.

Through OS X v10.11.4, you could sign the disk image itself (with `codesign -s "Developer ID Application: [your company]" example.dmg`), but the signature this creates is stored in the form of extended attributes attached to the image file. Actually, it creates three xattrs, named `com.apple.cs.CodeDirectory`, `com.apple.cs.CodeRequirements`, and `com.apple.cs.CodeSignature`. The critical thing to realize is that these attributes are filesystem metadata -- that is, they're attached to the file, not part of the file's contents. The HTTP protocol has very limited support for filesystem metadata, so when you upload or download via HTTP (or FTP or...), it only transfers the file's contents, and the xattrs are lost.

You can see the xattrs with the `ls -l@` command (and in even more detail with the `xattr` command):

```
$ ls -l@ example.dmg
-rw-r--r--@ 1 gordon  staff  338590 Nov 13  2013 example.dmg
        com.apple.cs.CodeDirectory         120 
        com.apple.cs.CodeRequirements      172 
        com.apple.cs.CodeSignature        8515 
        com.apple.diskimages.fsck           20 
        com.apple.diskimages.recentcksum         81
```

After downloading, the image will have lost those attributes (and probably gained `com.apple.quarantine` and `com.apple.metadata:kMDItemWhereFroms` from the download process), and hence will not be considered signed. The files contained in it, on the other hand, should still be properly signed (since their signatures are part of the image file's contents.)

Starting in OS X v10.11.5, `codesign` supports embedding the signature into the disk image itself, so that it will survive being downloaded over HTTP. Starting in v10.12, gatekeeper will enforce additional restrictions on apps in unsigned disk images that will prevent the app from loading additional content (mainly dynamic libraries) from the disk image, unless they're contained inside the app itself. If you don't know whether that's relevant to your app, go ahead and sign the disk image (actually, it's a good idea anyway), but be sure to run `codesign` under 10.11.5 or later or the signature won't be in a useful format!

Comment: I have discovered that when the quarantine is set, Gatekeeper saye the image would be broken and I should delete it. Any ideas?

Comment: How to preserve these codesigning attributes from removing.

Comment: @syammala With a web download, you can't preserve the code signature on the .dmg (unless you do something silly, like wrap that in another .dmg -- but then you can't sign that...). But you don't have to: don't sign the .dmg, sign the files inside it.

Comment: As of El Capitan 10.11.5, the DMG itself can be signed. That said, I do agree that the files inside should be signed too.

Comment: I have codesigned a DMG on 10.11.6 using a self-generated test certificate, which works fine, but the signature is still lost anyway after download. Do you have to maybe use a different command/option than `codesign -s <DevID> <DMG>`? I'm asking because the code signature is still part of the extended attributes, even though I'm on 10.11.6.

Comment: @JayB Very strange. That's the correct command (see [Apple's docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Security/Conceptual/CodeSigningGuide/Procedures/Procedures.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40005929-CH4-SW19). Is it possible you have an old version of the `codesign` binary in your $PATH? Try using `/usr/bin/codesign` expliictly.

Comment: I think I've found the reason. I tried to use codesigning on an encrypted DMG, and that doesn't seem to work, because (maybe) the encryption password takes up the space otherwise needed by the embedded codesigning certificate. Test DMG without encryption – https://transfer.sh/fyvCe/test.dmg – with signature intact (i.e. embedded), and the same DMG with encryption (password: 1234) – https://transfer.sh/11nd0R/test2.dmg – with signature always as xattr and lost at upload. See also the different file sizes: encryption seems to use a lot of bytes, possibly leaving no room for code signing.

Comment: @JayB I don't know the details of the image format, but as far as I can see signing encrypted images isn't supported (at least, with a new-style signature).

Comment: @JayB I think the issue is more likely the signature cannot be put inside the already-encrypted contents rather than a space issue.  One workaround is putting the encrypted, signed DMG inside a tar file.  The xattrs will survive this way if unpacked on another OS X filesystem.